# How can I do a IF using a function that returns two variables?

Tags: python, if-statement

I mean, if I have a function like this:

```
def example(foo, bar)
    ...
    return False, True
```

How can I compare the 2 returns?

```
if example(foo, bar):
```

I know that I can do this:

```
bool1, bool2 = example(foo,bar)
if bool1 and bool2:
    ...
```

But, can I compare the 2 of them without seting them in a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [all](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

```
if all(example(foo, bar)):
    # do something
```

If you need just one positive result you can use [any](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any).

Comment: Or `any`, depending on what they want

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even know that all() and any() exists

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to check. If you can send them to another function to do the checks, it will work without variables. Say if you want to check they're both True:

```
if all(example()):
    ...
```

or `any()` for one of them.

But if you say want to compare them with each other, you'd call the function twice:

```
if example()[0] == example()[1]:
```

and that's usually not desirable. So there I'd simply use the variable.

Comment: Second example is entirely different. What if both are `False`?

Comment: Wont this call the function twice? The comparison with one another?

Comment: thefourtheye: of course they're entirely different, I was showing different possibilities depending on what they want. Aswin: yes that calls the function twice, and I actually said that.

Comment: There are only three cases for two `bool`s (unless order matters); use `any`, `all` and `not any`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: There's also "exactly one", "both the same", and "at most one".

Answer (score 2):

simply use

```
if (True, True) == example(foo, bar):
```

Answer (score 0):

use all command:

```
if all(example(foo,bar)):
    # All returned values are True
```

Comment: No need to create another iterator on example, which already returns an iterable tuple. Also, `bool` is a built-in.

Comment: @IceArdor: Edited bool. removed the iterator too